# Weighted linear regression from log-likelihood?

Tags: regression, python, maximum-likelihood, modeling, weighted-regression

I have 500 time-series and for each one, I compute the best (aka max likelihood) parameter α in a model that I'm testing, along with the corresponding log-likelihood.

Now I wish to uncover a linear relationship between my α and some other property of the time-series, say β. What are my options regarding linear regressors which would somehow take into account the log-likelihoods? In other words, how do I translate log-likelihood into some sort of weighting or error-bars in a rigorous and meaningful way?

In the example below, for instance, most high-alpha points have low log-likelihoods and the correct slope is therefore smaller than a simple linear regression would yield.[image: Example input and desired output]

**edit:** For a more concrete example, let's assume my time-series are almost sinusoids with different periods $T$ and also have, say, a wavelength $\lambda$ assigned to them which should scale linearly with the period of oscillation. So my MLE routine returns $T_{1} = 42$ seconds with log-likelihood $1000$ and I know for this time series that $\lambda_{1} = 521 \pm 5$ nm. Some other series might return $T_{2} = 33$ seconds, log-likelihood $10$ and I know $\lambda_{2} = 314 \pm 7$ nm. How do I take the quality of the period estimate into account when fitting $T$ vs $\lambda$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The log likelihood can be negative so you have to throw that idea out straight away.

You should probably use inverse variance weighting instead.

The idea is that if the $\alpha$ you estimated has a high variance, it should have a low weight. This might match your intuition since the likelihood of a linear regression model is a function of the variance.

In fact, inverse variance weighting in a linear regression model leads to the best linear unbiased estimate (BLUE) of the trend-line, if that matters at all (sometimes a little bias isn't so bad).

Comment: Thanks that sounds good! What do you mean by "variance of $\alpha$" though - variance of the residuals of the model with parameter $\alpha$? Sorry I'm a stats noob!

Comment: @PetrJakubčík More precisely, it's the standard error of $\hat{\alpha}$. I can't tell you more. You only told us you estimated $\alpha$ with maximum likelihood. If it's from a linear model, then I think the answer to your question is yes. But any old MLE has some variance. You may have to do more digging.

Comment: Cool, I am using L-BFGS-B from Python's `scipy.optimize.minimize` and as it turns out, I can use the Hessian of the likelihood function at the maximum to estimate the standard error as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19836744/parameter-error-estimate-with-optimize-fmin-l-bfgs-b . Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you should try to use log-likelihood as some kind of weighting, the reason is that you're comparing different sets of data.

If $\alpha_1$ is the max likelihood estimate (MLE) for data set 1 and $\alpha_2$ is the MLE for data set two, then these are the best *for their data*.  The values of the likelihood may be different but they are the best parameters for their data.

If you're after error bounds on your $\alpha$ vs $\beta$ regression, bootstrap your data.

Better yet, you can set up a hierarchical model where you model the dependence between $\alpha$ and $\beta$ explicitly.  Without more information it's hard to give a concrete example though.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your ideas - I have now added a concrete example to the post. Any clue which of your proposed methods would be best in this case?

Comment: the inverse variance weighting AdamO suggested is similar in spirit to a hierarchical model and is probably simpler so I would go with that actually.